Proving $\sup(A) = \sup(X)$ where $A = \{ x \in [a, b] \mid f(x) \leq \gamma \}$ and $X = \{ x \in [a, b] \mid \sup(f([a, x]) \leq \gamma \}$
Suppose $f$ is a continuous function on $[a, b]$ and we are given $\gamma$ between $f(a)$ and $f(b)$. $A$ and $X$ are defined as follows:
$$
A = \{ x \in [a, b] \mid f(x) \leq \gamma \}\\
X = \{ x \in [a, b] \mid \sup(f([a, x]) \leq \gamma \}
$$
I want to prove $\sup(A) = \sup(X)$.
So far, I have shown that $\sup(X) \leq sup(A)$ since $X \subseteq A$. But how to show $\sup(X) < sup(A)$ cannot be true?

False for $f$ decreasing.

Counter-example: $a=0,b=1,f(x)=1-x, \gamma =\frac 1  2$. Here $X$ is empty and $A=[\frac 1  2,1]$.
False even if $f(a)\le \gamma \le f(b)$: Take $a=0,b=1, \gamma =0$, $f(x)=2x$ for $0 \le x \le \frac 1 2$ and $f(x)=2(1-x)$ for $\frac 1  2 \le x \le 1$. In this case $A=\{0,1\}$ and $X=\{0\}$.

what if we suppose $f(a) \leq \gamma \leq f(b)$?

@MrAmbiguneDL I have edited my answer to take care of this situation.
